# .gitattributes file not being respected by SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've set the contents of the `.gitattributes` file at my **project's root** to this:

```
members/2/dist/** text eol=LF
members/2/contacts/details/view/health/build/** text eol=LF

members/2/framework/cr.compressed-paths.js text eol=LF
members/2/framework/cr.loaderConfig.js text eol=LF
```

Files nested under both the dist/ and health/build paths should be stored with LF endings.  These files are all auto-generated from various Windows processes and that's what (seems) to be used.  And of course there's a members file right at the root of my project.

After running said process, I see pending changes under both of those directories, but with no visible changes shown in SourceTree.  Trying to commit yields this error:

`warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in members/2/contacts/details/view/health/build/allergy-component-bundle.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.`

Is my .gitattributes file set up wrongly?  Why is SourceTree trying to convert back to CRLF when .gitattributes says to use LF?

I'll also note that switching over to tortoiseGit shows these same files as changed, so it would seem that the problem is with my git configuration as opposed to SourceTree.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the best way to fix this is to just turn off normalization like so

```
members/2/dist/** -text
members/2/contacts/details/view/health/build/** -text

members/2/framework/cr.compressed-paths.js -text
members/2/framework/cr.loaderConfig.js -text
```